# How to run JUnit SpringJUnit4ClassRunner with Parametrized?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

The following code is invalid due to duplicate `@RunWith` annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfigTest.class})
public class ServiceTest {
}
```

But how can I use these two annotations in conjunction?

Comment: Here is another - and up to date - solution http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/08/parameterized-integration-tests-with.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are at least 2 options to do that:

1. Following http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/

   Your test needs to look something like this:

   ```
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfigTest.class})
    public class ServiceTest {

        private TestContextManager testContextManager;

        @Before
        public void setUpContext() throws Exception {
            //this is where the magic happens, we actually do "by hand" what the spring runner would do for us,
           // read the JavaDoc for the class bellow to know exactly what it does, the method names are quite accurate though
          this.testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
          this.testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
        }
        ...
    }
   ```
2. There is  a github project https://github.com/mmichaelis/spring-aware-rule, which builds on previous blog, but adds support in a generalized way

   ```
   @SuppressWarnings("InstanceMethodNamingConvention")
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServiceTest.class})
   public class SpringAwareTest {

       @ClassRule
       public static final SpringAware SPRING_AWARE = SpringAware.forClass(SpringAwareTest.class);

       @Rule
       public TestRule springAwareMethod = SPRING_AWARE.forInstance(this);

       @Rule
       public TestName testName = new TestName();

       ...
   }
   ```

So you can have a basic class implementing one of the approaches, and all tests inheriting from it.

Comment: Great, and with the first way you can then just use `@Autowired` on a component and it will be injected correctly. Also, I could use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration` and it worked fine, not sure what the difference is...

Comment: Your first link seems to be dead :-(

Comment: @mavarazy I've tried the first solution: Works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 86):

You can use SpringClassRule and SpringMethodRule - supplied with Spring

```
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(...)
public class MyTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    ...
```

Comment: @keyoxy Is it possible to run all tests in parallel?

Comment: can you add more explanation ? Why do we need these methods ?

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution with JUnit 4.12 without the need of Spring 4.2+.

JUnit 4.12 introduces [ParametersRunnerFactory](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/parameterized/ParametersRunnerFactory.html) which allow to combine parameterized test and Spring injection.

```
public class SpringParametersRunnerFactory implements ParametersRunnerFactory {
@Override
  public Runner createRunnerForTestWithParameters(TestWithParameters test) throws InitializationError {
    final BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters runnerWithParameters = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters(test);
    return new SpringJUnit4ClassRunner(test.getTestClass().getJavaClass()) {
      @Override
      protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
        final Object testInstance = runnerWithParameters.createTest();
        getTestContextManager().prepareTestInstance(testInstance);
        return testInstance;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

The factory can be added to test class to give full Spring support like [test transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html), [reinit dirty context](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) and [servlet test](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/ServletTestExecutionListener.html).

```
@UseParametersRunnerFactory(SpringParametersRunnerFactory.class)
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test-context.xml", "/mvc-context.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration
public class MyTransactionalTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext context;

  ...
}
```

If you need Spring context inside [@Parameters](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.Parameters.html) static method to provide parameters to test instances, please see my answer here [How can I use the Parameterized JUnit test runner with a field that's injected using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51677041/2592926).

Answer (score 0):

## Handle application context by yourself

What worked for me was having a `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` test class that managed the application context "by hand".

To do that I created an application context with the same string collection that would be in the `@ContextConfiguration`. So instead of having

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-config-file1.xml",
    "classpath:spring-config-file2.xml" })
```

I had

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
            "classpath:spring-config-file1.xml", "classpath:spring-config-file2.xml"  });
```

And for each @Autowired I needed I fetched it by hand from the created context:

```
SomeClass someBean = ctx.getBean("someClassAutowiredBean", SomeClass.class);
```

Do not forget to close the context at the end:

```
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) ctx).close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered long ago but I want to post my alternative solution:

I kept the spring configuration as it is:

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = XXXXWebApplication.class)

And instead of using annotation `@Parameters` I just put the variables in a global array and iterate over it when running the test to execute each single scenario.

The simplest.