# How do i initiate Spring @Autowired instances when running a Cucumber test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, cucumber

I'm able to initiate Spring when i'm debbuging StepDefinitions.java, but running the test from gradle produces *null*. Do I need an aditional glue?

Produces null: *gradle cucumber*

Produces null: running *myFeature.features*

Produces myService (working): running Stepdefinitions.java

I have tried the following code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = Application.class,
        loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Current StepDefinitions:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class StepDefinitions{
    private static String roll;

   @Autowired
   MyService myService;


    /** Reset all static values before running test cases    */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void resetValues() {
        roll = "";
    }

    //I use swedish, "Given"
    @Givet("Jag har rollen {string}")
    public void getRole(String roll) {
        assertNotNull(roll);
        this.roll = roll;
        myService.useRole(roll);
    }
}
```

gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
compile files('../libs/cucumber-spring-4.7.1.jar')
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:' + cucumberVersion
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:' + cucumberVersion
...
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + 
sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'steps/rufs', 
'src/test/resources/features', '--tags','@rufs']
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not getting JUnit involved anywhere. `RunWith` is used by JUnit, and this is what prompts Spring to get involved. When Cucumber is running as your suite, it's ignoring those annotations.

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/spring-txn

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting JUnit involved anywhere when running from Gradle. `@RunWith` is used by JUnit, and this in turn is what prompts Spring to get involved. When Cucumber is running as your suite, it's ignoring those annotations because it doesn't understand them.

You'll need to use JUnit as your suite (i.e. not run `cucumber.api.cli.Main`). You then have a problem because you need to use two "runners": Cucumber and Spring.

The way around this is JUnit's "rules" for one of the runners. Spring has a Rule, but as far as I can see Cucumber does not. In this case, use the Cucumber runner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
```

in combination with Spring's rules, as described here: [How to run JUnit SpringJUnit4ClassRunner with Parametrized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560734/how-to-run-junit-springjunit4classrunner-with-parametrized)

Comment: @mpkorstanje  `@RunWith` is a JUnit annotation, which he is already using in his code. If you want Spring integration with Cucumber then JUnit needs to be your suite. This is why when he runs the test from his IDE (i.e. with JUnit suite), it's working, but why from Gradle (Cucumber suite) it doesn't.