# Modify a parameter value used in multiple beans in Java unit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm wrting a JUnit to test a threshold value, which is passed from a `.properties` file like:

```
threshold=8
```

And I use a spring context to apply this threshold value:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/>

<si:channel id="thresholdInputChannel"/>
<si:recipient-list-router input-channel="thresholdInputChannel" default-output-channel="nullChannel">
    <si:recipient channel = "recipientChannel" selector-expression = "${threshold} > 0"/>
</si:recipient-list-router>
...

<si:chain input-channel = "fileTransformationChannel" output-channel="endChannel">
    <si:transformer method = "transform">
        <bean class = "fileTransformer" >
            <property name = "fixedProperties">
                <map>
                    <entry key="threshold" value="${threshold}"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </si:transformer>
</si:chain>
...
```

Before in the JUnit test, I used `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test.properties"})` to load the context and `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
and `@Autowired` to get all the channels defined in context file and it worked fine. But the problem is that like this I can test at one time one single value of `${threshold}` which is predefined in the `test.properties`.

To be able to change `${threshold}` value, I tried all the ways mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405422/how-can-i-use-the-parameterized-junit-test-runner-with-a-field-thats-injected-u):

1. Use `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`

   ```
   @Parameterized.Parameters
   public static List<Object[]> params() {
       return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
               {"0"},
               {"8"},
       });
   }
   ```

   but in this way I can't use injected beans any more, hence I lost the channels in JUnit.
2. `public abstract class AbstractJunitTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests` same problem with injected beans.
3. `@Value("${threshold}")
    private String threshold;` origin value don't get erased and invoke a problem of variable type as there is `selector-expression = "${threshold} > 0"` in context file.

I'd like to know if there is any other possible ways to do this. Dropping the context file and creating an `ApplicationConfig.class` with all the beans and parameters may be a solution but not a prefered one, as the context file is really great.

By the way, the reason I have to autowire the channels in JUnit is that I have to send a local file into the `fileTransformationChannel` and get it transformed in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager** for this:

Exemple:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class TargetClassTest {

    @Autowired
    private TargetClass instance;

    private TestContextManager testContextManager;

    String threshold;

    @Before
    public void setUpContext() throws Exception {
        this.testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        this.testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }


    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object []> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {"0"},{"8"},
        });
    }

    public TargetClassTest(String test) {
        this.threshold = test;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        String r = instance.businessMethod(threshold);
        Assert.assertEquals(threshold, r);
    }
}
```

In this case, it is possible after the initialization of @Before "inject" your Spring bean and use the parameterized execution to test several scenarios.

Comment: It's in which version of Spring ? I'm using 4.2.5 and there's no annotation `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2.  @SpringBootTest is just  class-level annotation that is used to determine how to load and configure an
  ApplicationContext for integration tests.