# Spring doesn't autowire fields when runner invokes '@Before' method

Tags: java, junit, concurrency, spring-test, junit-toolbox

I have following test:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfig.class)
public class OrderPlacementCancelTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestSessionsHolderPerf sessionsHolder;

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    private CommonCredentialSetter commonCredentialSetter;

    @Before
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {        
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!sessionsHolder.isClientLoggedIn() && attempts < 3) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            ++attempts;
        }

    }
     @Parameterized.Parameters()
     public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        ...
     }
```

and following runner:

```
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Class[] cls = {OrderPlacementCancelTest.class};
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(false, true), cls);
        logger.info("Failure count={}", result.getFailureCount());
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            logger.error(failure.getTrace());
        }
    }
```

When I start test via runner I see that **sometimes** method `login` marked as `@Before` throws `NullPointerException` because sessionsHolder is null.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Might have to do with mixing in `@Parameterized`. Perhaps using  `TestContextManager` to initialize the class could avoid the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522237/3280538

Comment: @flakes you are correct, please add answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `@Parameterized` does not mix well with junit rules. One option would be to replace the `Rule` by performing the logic in the constructor of the parameterized test class, or calling a setup method at the beginning of your test methods.

In either case you can use `TestContextManager` to populate your test class with the `@AutoWired` values like this:

```
private TestContextManager testContextManager;

@Before
public void login() throws Exception {
    testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
    testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
```